# Hide/Remove ads with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make a program that detects ads and then removes them. This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = input('Enter URL to detect ads from: ')

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://'+url)

all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
print(' ')


for iframe in all_iframes:
   browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
   print("Ad Found")
   browser.switch_to.default_content()

print(' ')
print('Total Ads: ' + str(len(all_iframes)))
```

My question is that is there a way to remove/hide these ads my program has detected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply set `hidden` attribute to each `iframe` to make them invisible as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = input('Enter URL to detect ads from: ')

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://'+url)

all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
if len(all_iframes) > 0:
    print("Ad Found\n")
    browser.execute_script("""
        var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"); 
        for(var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++)
             {
                 elems[i].hidden=true;
             }
                          """)
    print('Total Ads: ' + str(len(all_iframes)))
else:
    print('No frames found')
```

P.S. Note that not every `iframe` on page is an advertisement!

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you tell me where exactly i should put the code you answered?

Comment: Is there a way to find all ads on a page using ad servers on this link: [link](http://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/iplist.php?ipformat=&showintro=1&mimetype=plaintext) or is there any way of finding all ads on a page?

Comment: Do you want to check hypertext reference of each `iframe` element's embedded link and compare its origin with each of adserver `IP`? Also I'm not sure that there is a way to determine whether it's an ad on `iframe` or not. There could be attributes like `title="3rd party ad content"` or `name="google_ads_frame3"`, but it's not a strong rule... I think you might need to open new ticket to get this info

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I will make a new ticket soon

Comment: You can mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your current issue